# Coreplot rendering Issue?

Tags: ios, ipad, core-plot

In my app, I am using Core-plot library to plot Vertical bar chart. When user taps on bar it should navigate to the another View-controller. (It will be off same view-controller's instance). When i push like this only for example 12-15 times i receiving memory warning & App crashes.

Did anyone faced same issue while using Core-plot library?

Thanks
Naveen.

Comment: i also have the same problem. I can draw tons of the othe graphs, but only 3 or 4 bar charts

Comment: **[barChartView removeFromSuperview];** - Before assigning new view, Remove older view from super view & also release it. And then assign new view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your app by memory tools in Instruments.app. Maybe you can [find some memory leaks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingLeaks.html). Memory warnings appears when your project use a lot of memory. And there is no reason to think that problem is in CorePlot. (as you said you creates more than 10 view controllers. Do you release them?)